# How do you create a Perl module?

Tags: perl, module

How do you write a module for Perl? In Python you can use:

```
# module.py
def helloworld(name):
    print "Hello, %s" % name

# main.py
import module
module.helloworld("Jim")
```

Answer (score 28):

A class:

```
# lib/Class.pm
package Class;
use Moose;

# define the class

1;
```

A module that exports functions:

```
# lib/A/Module.pm
package A::Module;
use strict;
use warnings;
use Sub::Exporter -setup => {
    exports => [ qw/foo bar/ ],
};

sub foo { ... }
sub bar { ... }

1;
```

A script that uses these:

```
# bin/script.pl
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use FindBin qw($Bin);
use lib "$Bin/../lib";

use Class;
use A::Module qw(foo bar);


print Class->new;
print foo(), bar();
```

Comment: Interesting...in all the modules I've seen, the way to do export has been with "our @ISA qw(Exporter); our @EXPORT = qw(funcx funcy funcz)", even in PBP.

Comment: Exporter is built-in, but it sucks.  S::Ex is much ... sexier :)

Comment: True.  But then you have to distribute Sub::Exporter with your module.  Dependencies suck!  (But I guess, if you're using Moose, you've already headed down that road!)

Comment: If you don't want dependencies, I suggest writing your software in CPU microcode instead of Perl.  Of course, then you'll have a dependency on a certain model of CPU...

Answer (score 25):

Basically you create a file named `Yourmodulename.pm`, whose contents are:

```
package Yourmodulename;

# Here are your definitions

1; # Important, every module should return a true value
```

Then the program that uses the module will look like:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;            # These are good pragmas
use warnings;      

# Used modules
use Carp;              # A module that you'll probably find useful
use Yourmodulename;    # Your module
```

You may want to organize your modules in a hierarchical (and hopefully logical) way. To do so you create a tree of directories like:

Your/Module.pm
Your/Other/Module.pm

And then in your program:

```
use Your::Module;
use Your::Other::Module;
```

There are more facilities to export functions and variables from your module, you can take a look at Henning Koch's ["Writing serious Perl: The absolute minimum you need to know"](http://www.netalive.org/tinkering/serious-perl/).

Answer (score 14):

An "exact" equivalent of your Python example in Perl would look like this:

```
# MyModule.pm
package MyModule;

sub helloworld { 
    my ( $name ) = @_;
    print "Hello, $name\n";
}

1;

# main.pl
use MyModule;
MyModule::helloworld( 'Jim' );
```

For more, see [the entry for `package` in perlfunc](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/package.html) documentation.  For much more, see the [perlmod](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html) documentation.

Answer (score 11):

The last third of [Intermediate Perl](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596102067/) is devoted to module creation.

Whenever you want to know how to do something in Perl, check perltoc, the table of contents for the Perl documentation:

```
% perldoc perltoc
```

Several parts of the core Perl documentation can help you:

- [perlmod](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html)
- [perlmodlib](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmodlib.html)
- [perlmodstyle](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmodstyle.html)
- [perlnewmod](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlnewmod.html)
- [perltoot: Tom's Object-Oriented Tutorial](http://perldoc.perl.org/perltoot.html)
- [perlboot: Barnyard Object-Oriented Tutorial](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlboot.html)

Good luck,

Answer (score 6):

One minor detail that the answers so far haven't mentioned is that, if you have a (preferably small) module which is purpose-specific enough that it will never be reused, you can put it into the same file as the main program or another package:

```
# main.pl

# Since this is a beginner question, I'll also point out that you should
# *always* use strict and warnings.  It will save you many headaches.
use strict;
use warnings;

MyModule::helloworld('Jim');
AnotherModule::helloworld('Jim');

package MyModule; # Still in main.pl!

sub helloworld { 
    my ( $name ) = @_;
    print "Hello, $name\n";
}

package AnotherModule; # Yep, still main.pl

sub helloworld {
    my $name = shift;
    print "Another hello to $name\n";
}
```

This isn't used often because it gives you a package that's defined in a file whose name isn't the same as the package's, which can get confusing because you have to `use`/`require` the filename, but reference it in code by the package name.

Also note that the `1;` is only needed as the final line of each file which is included via `use`/`require`.  In this case, I didn't need it because it's in `main.pl`.  If you put multiple packages into the same file, you only need a `1;` at the end of the file, not after each package.

Answer (score 5):

The most traditional way of setting up a module is as follows:

```
package Foo::Bar;
our @ISA       = qw(Exporter);       # Tells perl what to do with...
our @EXPORT    = qw(sub1 sub2 sub3); # automatically exported subs
our @EXPORT_OK = qw(sub4 sub5);      # exported only when demanded

# code for subs, constants, package variables here

1;  # Doesn't actually have to be 1, just a 'true' value.
```

and as others have said, you can use it like so:

```
use Foo::Bar;
```

Answer (score 2):

h2xs -XA -n My::Module

h2xs is a utility that comes as standard with perl, intended for assisting in building linked modules including linked C headers/code, but which can be used to build a complete skeleton of a pure perl module (with the -XA flags), including things like a test directory, a README file, a Makefile, and a Manifest. (a good article outlining the details here: http://perltraining.com.au/tips/2005-09-26.html )

It's kinda old-school, but it's worth looking at even if just for all the reminders it gves you about getting everything right (tests, documentation, version numbers, export and export_ok lists, all the easy-to-forget stuff...)

You'll end up with a "Module.pm" file inside a "My" directory (from the "My::Module") that looks like this:

```
package My::Module;

use 5.008008;
use strict;
use warnings;

require Exporter;

our @ISA = qw(Exporter);

# Items to export into callers namespace by default. Note: do not export
# names by default without a very good reason. Use EXPORT_OK instead.
# Do not simply export all your public functions/methods/constants.

# This allows declaration       use My::Module ':all';
# If you do not need this, moving things directly into @EXPORT or @EXPORT_OK
# will save memory.
our %EXPORT_TAGS = ( 'all' => [ qw(

) ] );

our @EXPORT_OK = ( @{ $EXPORT_TAGS{'all'} } );

our @EXPORT = qw(

);

our $VERSION = '0.01';


# Preloaded methods go here.

1;
__END__
# Below is stub documentation for your module. You'd better edit it!

=head1 NAME

My::Module - Perl extension for blah blah blah
```

Answer (score 2):

```
cpanm Module::Starter::PBP
perl -MModule::Starter::PBP=setup
module-starter --module=My::Module
```